# Storing different object as void* and casting from and to void*

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I am trying to store different objects in one global table with void* pointer. Problem is how to retrieve the void* object back. If I have one common base class, say Object , I can always store the void* pointer as Object and then cast back to Object*. From Object* I can cast further to the specific type.

```
class Object{};
class A : public Object{ virtual ~A()}
class B : public A { }
class C : public Object{ virtual ~C()} 
class D: public C{};

A* aObj = new B;
void* v = static_cast<Object*>(aObj);      

// scenario 1, try to get as A*
Object* obj = static_cast<Object*> (v);
A* vaobj = dynamic_cast<A*> ( obj); // ok

// scenario 2, try to get it as C*
Object* obj = static_cast<Object*> (v);
C* caobj = dynamic_cast<C*> ( obj); // ok, caObj will be null so I can throw exception if this happens
```

I know that the solution when I have one common base class is safe, but problem is I can't have common base class, because I don't control all the different types, and can't derive them from Object. The code when I don't have common base class:

```
class A{ virtual ~A() }; class B : public A{};
class C{ virtual ~C() }; class D : public C{};

A* aObj = new B;
void* v = dynamic_cast<void*>(aObj);// to actually store the address of B

// scenario 1, try to retrieve object as A*
A* aObj2 = static_cast<A*>(v);
A* aa = dynamic_cast<A*> (aObj2); // aa should be non null

// scenario 2, try to retrieve object as C*
C* cObj = static_cast<C*>(v);
C* cc = dynamic_cast<C*>(cObj); // cc should be null
```

Questions :

Scenario 1:
I store the void* pointer with the address of B ( that dynamic_cast to void* does ). then I do 
static_cast with A* which I know it is not safe, because I originally stored the object in the void* ptr as B*, and I know that we must store and retrieve the same type of pointer in void*. But, then I do further cast with dynamic_cast to verify that the object is actually right. so this should work, and dynamic_cast should give me the right object ?

Scenario 2:
Same, but now I am fist static_casting to C*, and then further dynamic_casting , and this time I should get NULL, cause the stored object was actually B.

Comment: I would say that "this smells bad". In other words, you probably should think of some other solution. Why do you need to store objects that are unrelated in a table? Maybe you should store a wrapper object instead?

Comment: No I definitely should store the object pointers. So I need some solution, I guess this is common problem,but having hard time to get it right

Comment: But then you end up having to do a bunch of `if ptr != NULL ...`, which is not good for readability of the code, and not good for the performance. Perhaps you can explain what your actual problem is, not "how you are trying to solve it", because I'm pretty sure it's the wrong solution. (Oh, and `dynamic_cast` is typically quite slow too!)

Comment: No thats ok, I will not have bunch of checks if ptr!=NULL, that will be in one place, i.e request to get object from void* should come from one template function which will specify the type how to get the void* . In that function I will throw exception if ptr == NULL.

Comment: Using the options you've given the only easy way I can see of doing this is turning your table into a table of structs which store both the void* and type information (perhaps as an integer or size_t: 0 == A, 1 == B, 2 == C etc.) It's a really nasty hackish solution, but at least you're then sure you're converting back to the right type. I agree with what Mats is saying though, in that there must be some better way.

Comment: Yes but problem is , that if I store the object originally as B*, I should be able to get it as A* also, cause B inherits A. And if I store type information for each object in the table, then for B* I should also store that is also A*, besides B. Which seams not as good solution, given that B can inherit from other classes as well, and not just from A

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to do this than storing `void*`. If you are trying to have polymorphic containers based on _functionality_ rather than inheritance, look into _Concept-Based Polymorphism_. Check [here](http://thinkthencode.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/concept-based-polymorphism.html) for a brief introduction and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpMYeUFXv8) for more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Storing void* is almost never necessary in C++, whereas in C it is commonplace. C++ has better, more type-safe alternatives. For example, maybe you could use Boost.Any?

Comment: no can't use boost::any. boost::any also requires to retrieve the exact type that is stored. So I can't retrieve it as base class ptr, if derived ptr is stored.

Answer (score 0):

As many commenters have already said, storing void* in C++ is really not necessary. If you don't have control over the types you're storing, make a container for them. That way you can control its definition and behaviour(And derive it from Object, if you wish).

Very rough working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Object{
    public:
    virtual ~Object(){};
};

template<typename T>
class Container : public Object{
    T* v;
    public:
    Container(T* b):v(b){}

    T* value(){
        return v;
    }

    void deleteContained(){
        delete v;
    }
};

class foo{
public:
    virtual string say(){
        return "foo";
    }
};
class bar: public foo{
public:
    string say(){
        return "bar";
    }
};

int main(){
    Object* o;
    o = new Container<foo>(new bar);

    Container<foo>* fooCon = dynamic_cast<Container<foo>*>(o);
    foo* fooObj = fooCon->value();
    // Since you now have the object in a foo*, you can dynCast it to a bar* if you like.
    bar* barObj = dynamic_cast<bar*>(fooObj);

    // Cast to the wrong container type is NULL.
    Container<int>* nullInt = dynamic_cast<Container<int>*>(o);
    if(nullInt)
        cout << "Cast Successful." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Cast failed." << endl;

    // Both will print "bar", since "o" contains a bar object.
    cout << fooObj->say() << endl;
    cout << barObj->say() << endl;

    ((Container<foo>*)o)->deleteContained();
    delete o;
}
```

Output:

```
Cast failed.
bar
bar
```

Comment: close, but doesnot take inheritance into account. That is I want to cast from B* to A*, if B is inherited from A.  Object* obj = new Container<B*>(B()); and then later do Container<A*> aObj = dynamic_cast<Container<A*>>(obj); it will fail

Comment: I see. I will try to put up a more suitable solution then.